# Ruby - No implicit conversion of false into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting the following error with the code explained below.
"no implicit conversion of false into String"

```
  def search_form(target, search)
    raw("<span class='no_print'>" <<
            form_tag('/' + target + '/', :method => :get) <<
            text_field_tag(:search, search) <<
            submit_tag('Search', data: { disable_with: "Searching..." }) <<
            !search.nil? ? link_to('Clear', root_path, class: 'clearingLink') : "" <<
            '</form>' <<
            '</span>' <<
            form_focus('search'))
  end

!search.nil? ? link_to('Clear', root_path, class: 'clearingLink') : "" <<
This is the line I have added recently. Can anyone please let me know what is the wrong with this ?
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `ruby-on-rails` I wonder why you build that HTML snippet by string concatenation and do not use a view for that?

Comment: Hey. This code snippet have been added in the controller itself. I was given this project to work....

Answer (score 3):

`"str" << false` is the minimal example for the error you are experiencing. The error is the result of misunderstanding relating to operator precedence. Notably, `?:` is of lower precedence than `<<`; so

```
a << b ? c : d << e
```

(where `b` is your `!search.nil?`) evaluates as

```
(a << b) ? c : (d << e)
```

while you hoped it would evaluate as

```
a << (b ? c : d) << e
```

Solution: add parentheses to ensure the desired evaluation order.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I corrected it in this way.
(!search.nil? ? link_to('Clear', root_path, class: 'clearingLink') : "") <<

Comment: "Solution: add parentheses to ensure the desired evaluation order." – Personally, I prefer the following solution: never use the conditional operator. It is not necessary in Ruby. The conditional operator exists in C, because operators are expressions and `if` is a statement, so if you want to use a conditional expression, you need the conditional operator. But in Ruby, `if` is a conditional expression, so there is no need for the conditional operator, it is completely useless. A large amount of questions on [so] involving the conditional operator in Ruby turn out to be precedence problems, …

Comment: … whereas the conditional expression just has the precedence you would expect it to have: `unless search.nil? then link_to('Clear', root_path, class: 'clearingLink') else "" << '</form>' << '</span>' << form_focus('search')) end`.